# How i can change font to UITextView in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, fonts

Hy guys I want that my `textView` have this font: `"Apple SD Gothic Light"`...
I used this code here belong:

```
if (titolo.text == NSLocalizedString("SEVENTH_ANNOTATION_TITLE", comment: "")){
    // aggiungo le immagini all'array
    pageImages = [UIImage(named: "TeatroMassimoBellini1.png")!,
                  UIImage(named: "TeatroMassimoBellini2.png")!,
                  UIImage(named: "TeatroMassimoBellini3.png")!]

    textFieldDescrizione.text = NSLocalizedString("SEVENTH_ANNOTATION_DESCRIPTION", comment: "")
    textFieldDescrizione.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle("AppleSDGothicNeo-Light")
    textFieldDescrizione.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Justified
}
```

but it doesn't work.... Can you help me?
Sorry for my english! :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this :

```
textFieldDescrizione.font = UIFont(name: "NameOfTheFont", size: 20)
```

Answer (score 4):

For Swift 4 , this worked for me

```
textView.font = UIFont(name: "Courier", size: 20)
```